# Policy Gradient Methods - Proof

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, machine-learning

I'm trying to get a grasp of reinforcement learning and among the references I came across [Policy Gradient Methods for Reinforcement Learning with Function Approximation](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1713-policy-gradient-methods-for-reinforcement-learning-with-function-approximation.pdf)

The paper is really short and the appendix is what I'm mostly interested in. In appendix the theorem proven is

> **Theorem 1 (Policy Gradient)** For any MDP, in either the average reward or start-state formulations,
> $$
> \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial \theta} = \sum_{s} d^{\pi}(s) \sum_a \frac{\partial \pi(s,a)}{\partial \theta} Q^{\pi}(s,a)
> $$

When I go in appendix 1 I understand all the math (it's mostly chain rule and substitutions), however it's the very beginning that confuses me. The proof indeed starts with

$$
\frac{\partial V^{\pi}(s)}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \sum_a \pi(s,a) Q^{\pi}(s,a) \;\;\; \forall s \in \mathcal{S}
$$

The equality is "by definition" true, however the quantity $V^{\pi}(s)$ is not defined in the paper. Does anyone know or can clarify maybe?

Comment: Here, $V^\pi(s)$ is the state value of $s$. Its definition is already suggested in this equation though not given explicitly. The definition of $Q^\pi(s,a)$ is given in Section 1.

Comment: So it is being **defined** as $V^{\pi}(s) = \sum_a \pi(s,a) Q^{\pi}(s,a)$ right there on the spot?

Comment: Yes. Furthermore, the definition of the q value (both given in the paper) also varies from the case of discounted reward to the case of average reward. In either case, the state values satisfy the well-known Bellman equation (when it is the average reward case, the Bellman equation becomes the Poisson equation)

Comment: What's the Poisson equation in this context?